# Limits of the Geometric mean

Tags: limits

Any hints on the following problem of limits:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{i}{n}\right)\right]^{(1/n)}$$

Using AM-GM inequality an upper bound can be found, but how to find the exact value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take logarithms and you obtain a Riemmann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1\log\Bigl(\sin\frac{\pi\,x}{2}\Bigr)\,dx.
$$